GitLab Pull mirroring repositories from a simple http filestorage, fails
In an offline environment, I am trying to setup GitLab Pull mirror repositories from a simple http server with a clone of the project (all on same offline network). I have configured GitLab to pull from the http server, but GitLab fails with "repository not found".
Git cloned project can be retrieved from http://myserver.net/git_project and requires no authentication.
I can get the whole cloned project with a simple wget -r http://myserver.net/git_project.
This gives me all files/folders of the cloned project ('.git/', 'src/' etc.).
The GitLab server have been setup to pull with different variations of the "Git repository URL" field, to make it work. I have tried the following variations:
http://myserver.net/git_project
http://myserver.net/git_project.git 
http://myserver.net/git_project/.git
But GitLab keeps saying it cant find the repo.
Is it because the GitLab Pull, expects a real GitHub or GitLab server, and cannot retrieve files directly?
I hope someone can help me :-)
Summary:
I have tried setting GitLab to mirror using pull from http://myserver.net/git_project
I expect GitLab to retrieve the cloned project from http://myserver.net/git_project
Result is, that GitLab Pull Mirroring fails, saying "Repository not found".
Edit: Typo
